# How do I calculate the derivative of kurtosis and entropy?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent, kurtosis, derivative

I'm using kurtosis and entropy as penalty terms in my neural network's cost function. Need to back-propagate the error. For that I need a quick way to estimate the derivative (the gradient eventually). Numerically calculating is too slow, I only use it to check if my implementation is correct or not.

In Matlab:

```
kurtosis = mean((mean(v)-v)^4) / (mean((mean(v)-v)^2)^2);
```

equivalent with:

```
kurtosis = (sum((v-mean(v))^4)/length(v)) / (var(v,1)^2)
```

Then I also take:

```
kurtosisPenalty = sqrt((kurtosis-3)^2)
```

Because I don't care if it's sub-gaussian or super-gaussian.

I've tried as derivative:

```
mv = mean(v)-v;

kurt = (mean(mv.^4) ./ (mean(mv.^2)^2))-3;

kurtsqr = sqrt(kurt.^2);

kurtosisDerivL(m) = 0.5./kurtsqr * 2*(kurt) * ...
    (mean(4*mv) * (mean(mv.^2)^2) - mean(mv.^4) * mean(2*mv.^2)*mean(2*mv)) ./ ((mean(mv.^2)^2).^2);
```

But the gradient that this leads to is not even close to the numerically calculated gradient.

With entropy I couldn't even think of how to derive.

Comment: You didn't tell us with respect to which variable/parameter you want the derivative ...

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen I think it’s quite clear from the question if you have ever done error backpropagation